# How to create exe file using VBS

Tags: vbscript, exe

How to make executable file with VBS. There is a code for txt but how to change it to make from this exe

```
    Dim objFSO 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const Append = 8 
Dim FDir
FDir = ("Area where file will be saved") 
Const FName_Ext = "Title of document.txt"
Dim Final 
Final = FDir + FName_Ext

Dim objtxt 
set objtxt = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Final, True)
Set objtxt = Nothing

Dim FWrite 
Set FWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Final, Append)

FWrite.WriteLine("this is the text in the file.!!! hahaha lol wohoo yada yada yada. okay done!")  
FWrite.Close()
Set FWrite = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: What exactly is the data you want to add to the exe file? You can name the file `foo.exe` instead of `foo.txt` but that doesn't magically make it a _valid_ executable file.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Why do you think you need to have a VBScript create an executable file? What is the purpose of that file? Where does the content come from?

Comment: There are tools you can use to convert a VBScript into an executable, if that is what you are after. Unfortunately this is a feature often used to create malware, and the resulting executables are therefore often summarily blocked by security software.

Answer (score 0):

Get familiar with [PE Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format) . Short, this is a lot of binary data that tells windows where to find what when it starts to execute your file. Although vbs was not designed for binary magic, the simple text way does the trick if you have saved your binary data into a variable, at least according to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/809e74f4-160a-4a81-be23-7b245299a9d2/vbscript-to-create-a-binary-file?forum=ITCG) microsoft doc.